# Specifying hydrators for AbstractDbMapper in ZF2

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework2

I've made a new module in my ZF2 application that has a model and a mapper. In the Module.php file I have created a factory for the AbstractDbMapper as follows:

```
public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'ZfcProductMapper' => function ($sm) {
                    $mapper = new ProductMapper();
                    $mapper->setDbAdapter($sm->get('ZendDbAdapterAdapter'));
                    $mapper->setEntityPrototype(new Product());
                    $mapper->setHydrator(new **????**);
                    return $mapper;
                }
            ),
        );
    }
```

I currently have my hydrator in the Product class as 2 functions 'extract' and 'hydrate'. My question is, how can I set the hydrator in my factory as being in the Product class and not as a whole new class?

Also, when are these hydrator functions called? At the moment I'm calling them myself when I need an array and not an object (for JSON for example) so what I'm really wondering is why does the factory need to know about these hydrators since only I know when they are needed.